# Help with R, grouping together rows.

Tags: statistics

I have data in R that is laid out as follows:

First column is the group number (55 in total)

Second column is group size, i.e. number of people in a group (max. group size is 3)

Third column is the number of females in the group

Layout is pictured below.

[image]

I'm looking to categorise the groups into either all female, all male or mixed, however I'm struggling on how to do this with the way in the data is laid out.

Not sure if help can be provided on here, if not please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a programming question? Is this a derive all-maleness, all-femaleness, mixed question? Why are groups repeated? What are the aggregation methods that work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only options for a person are Male or Female then you can create column that would be `males = size-females`. This can be leveraged to make group labels:
`all_male = (females == 0 & males > 0)`, `all_female = (males == 0 & females > 0)`, `mixed = (females > 0 & males > 0)`.

Where I am using & to be the "and" operation between two True/False statements. == means equals evaluation, = means assignment. Other symbols are typical I believe.

After that you will have to do some aggregation to make sure that you are at one row per group. You haven't provide sufficient information to determine what that looks like.

Comment: Thanks, all sorted.